# UIView standard Protocol for subclass

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview, protocols

At WWDC 15 Apple made it very clear that classes should start with a base protocol. Here you can find why I think that https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/.   My question is if I have a class that I used to subclass from UIView what protocol should I start from. We will say its a UILabel so I just want it to display something but not be intractable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the base protocol **only** if you are creating some new class or structure inside your application. If you need `UIKit` or `Foundation` you should stick with plain subclassing (in your case from `UIView`) since those frameworks are old and their core functionality is still written in Objective C which is an object-oriented language.

Comment: Yeah I am creating a custom subclass so it's a new class

Comment: But you said in your question that it is a UIView subclass, so it is not a new class